# Selenium find and click img with a text inside div

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am new to xpaths in selenium and trying to click on Next> image/button in the code below. I have tried following two xpaths but its not working and giving no element not found error.

```
By.xpath("//div[@class='pzbtn-mid']/img[contains(text(), \"Next >\")]"))
By.xpath("//div[@class='pzbtn-mid']/img[contains(text(), 'Next >')]"))
```

What am i doing wrong here?

```
<div class="pzbtn-mid" data-bindprops="innerHTML" data-click="...."> ==$0
<img src="webwb/zblankimage.gif" alt="" class="pzbtn-i">
"Next >"
<img alt="" src="webwb/zblankimage.gif" class="pzbtn-i">
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to `click()` on the **Next>** image/button you can use the following `xpath` :

```
By.xpath("//div[@class='pzbtn-mid']/img[@class='pzbtn-i' and @src='webwb/zblankimage.gif']"))
```

*Note* : The text **Next >** is not within any of the `<img>` tags but within the `<div>` tag. Hence to click on the *image/button* you have to reach till the `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use xpath below,

```
By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'pzbtn-mid') and contains(.,'Next >')]//img")
```

It clicks the first image if the img belongs to next. Othervise you should click the second img like below;

```
driver.findElementsBy((By.xpath("above xpath")).get(1));
```